# IPFS not returning anything

Tags: solidity, dapps, ipfs

```
const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client')
const ipfs = ipfsClient({ host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' }) 

uploadAsset = (cost) => {
    console.log("Submitting file to ipfs...")
    ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (error, result) => {
      console.log('Ipfs result', result)
      if(error) {
        console.error(error)
        return
      }
    console.log("no error")  
      this.setState({ loading: true })
      this.state.dstock.methods.uploadAsset(result[0].hash, cost).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
    })
```

The function uploadAsset is being called by a child component which passes the cost.
I am unable to get the resut and the below mentioned thing comes on chrome console

[image]